# Lumia 535 camera is getting blur day by day

Tags: lumia, camera, nokia-lumia-535

I am using `Microsoft Lumia 535` ( Model `RM-1090` ) with `windows 8.1 update`, in my phone, I have purchased phone before 2 years.

But I found that its rear camera is getting blur day by day.

Can any one help me out what can I do to make it good. As service centre of Nokia has been closed in India. So unable to access service centre there.